# Sample of lossless image rotate via commons imaging

Tags: java, image, jpeg, imaging, lossless

I found that commons imaging library fits my needs best of all, but there is a lack samples of this library usage.
Does anyone have an example how to rotate jpeg image lossless (i.e. by changing file metadata only)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a class RotatedIcon (see links) that can be used like this

```
        if (imageOrientation.equals("3")) {
          rotatedIcon = new RotatedIcon(imageIcon, RotatedIcon.Rotate.UPSIDE_DOWN);
        } else if (imageOrientation.equals("6")) {
          rotatedIcon = new RotatedIcon(imageIcon, RotatedIcon.Rotate.DOWN);
        } else if (imageOrientation.equals("8")) {
          rotatedIcon = new RotatedIcon(imageIcon, RotatedIcon.Rotate.UP);
        }
```

imageOrientation is a property of image meta data (e.g. EXIF)

https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/

https://github.com/griffon/griffon-javatips-plugin/blob/master/src/main/com/wordpress/tipsforjava/swing/RotatedIcon.java

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for an answer but what I wanted is to rotate image lossless, with preserving EXIF data in the image.
There are at least two libraries, which may do the trick: LLJTran and Commons Imaging (ex. Sanselan). LLJTran does not support some modern EXIF fields, thus I wanted to rotate JPEGs with Apache Commons Imaging but cannot find a code sample for it.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868013/editing-jpeg-exif-data-with-java) on how to add/remove meta data using the Commons Imaging library.
The tag you would want to set is `org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.constants.TiffTagConstants#TIFF_TAG_ORIENTATION`.