# Is possible to write an EXIF tag with metadata extractor lib?

Tags: exif, metadata-extractor

I would like to change some clipping Path name of a lot of images.
Is there any possibility to achieve this with the *metadata-extractor* library?

Something like:

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(f);            
PhotoshopDirectory directoryPshp = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(PhotoshopDirectory.class);
if(directoryPshp != null)
{
    directoryPshp.setString(PhotoshopDirectory.TAG_CLIPPING_PATH_NAME, cpName);
}
```

It hasn't failed, but it did nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Metadata Extractor doesn't support writing metadata to files. It only supports extracting.

Comment: any other way to write this exif tag?

Comment: A quick search turned up this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868013/editing-jpeg-exif-data-with-java