# How to manipulate EXIF data using IIOMetadata?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, exif, javax.imageio

I'm looking for a solution that retains EXIF data of a JPEG/PNG or video files and allows me to populate copyright and comments metadata.

Here's my requirement -

- Files are uploaded to AWS S3 via our portal
- My program must apply watermark on original image and downscaled (/resized) image and copy to a different bucket
- I'm losing EXIF data when I'm doing the above (I'm using Lambda function to trigger the java library to resize and watermark)
- I have been exploring various options including '*apache commons imaging library*'.  I could read the data using this and there are examples how to populate metadata [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868013/editing-jpeg-exif-data-with-java).  However, I'm wondering if similar stuff could be achieved with IIOMetadata (*javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata*).

As mentioned above, I need to populate *copyright* and *comments* on all media files.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement that the copyright and comment is stored in Exif metadata? Or can you use COM marker in JPEG and iTXt chunk for PNG? Can you use XMP? If Exif is required, how do you (plan to) store that in the PNG?

Comment: @haraldK, majority of the images are of JPEG format and current implementation is using _javax.imageio_ & _java.awt.Graphics2D_ libraries.  Hence, looking for a solution that doesn't prompt a whole lot of changes.  Of course, if no option available, I may have to refresh the implementation to support all usecases.

Comment: That may be.. But it doesn't really address any of my questions above, regarding requirements. The reason why this is important, is, it's possible but not trivial to write Exif using IIOMetadata. Also, the PNG spec does not cover Exif metadata, so how you plan to store that isn't clear-cut, even if Exif is required. And finally, for both formats, there are alternatives that may work, and will be much easier to implement.

Comment: @haraldk, I might have been ambitious in asking for PNG too.  For now, the solution is needed only for JPEG. And, you are proposing COM marker as the best option and easy to implement. is that correct?  Could you please point me to a sample implementation?