# Is there any way to update the Exif tag in jpg file using java?

Tags: java, jpeg, exif

Im cleaning up my jpg files by tagging them in categories. However, the amount is too much to do it with hand operation so Im trying to tag the jpg files using java code (to automate it).

I googled several times but could not find the answer.

```
// What I want is something like this.
String path = "F:\\test.jpg"
File test_file = new File(path);
test_file.property.tag = "school";
test_file.property.tag = "xxxxCity";
```

None since I don't know the source code of doing it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for, is a way to update the Exif information in the JPEGs. ExifTool can probably be scripted to update such tags. Here's [an answer to a similar question that suggests using Apache Commons Imaging (Sanselan)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873897/1428606).

Comment: See . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400351/android-exif-data-always-0-how-to-change-it this link

Comment: What kind of tag do you want to update ? JPEG EXIF metadata are essentially dedicated to date/time, camera settings (aperture, shutter speed...), gps location. Where do you plan to store your "category" information ?