# Adding new field to GPS directory of image in JAVA

Tags: java, exif

I want to add a new field to the GPS directory of the image in JAVA.
Now existing fields are like this.
[gps data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni1Gv.png)

Existing filed:

---GPS---
Latitude: 41:25:33
Longitude: 4:48:14
Altitude: 776

I want to add new fields now. like this.
[new field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMVqu.png)
---GPS---
Latitude: 41:25:33
Longitude: 4:48:14
Altitude: 776
Roll: 224
Yaw:123
Pitch:221

Who can help me? Please share me any examples.

Comment: Please don't include links to external images. Just copy the text into your question, so this question will always have value to others, even after the external images die.   That said, please post what you've tried so far to get better help from the community.

Comment: Ok. But I can't copy the image here directly. Because I have no enough reputation here.
I will add more descriptions in this post.

Comment: Did you looked at [UserDefinedFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html) ?

Comment: Yes. I checked that. But it is not answered to my problem.
I am using org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.
I think there is some option to add new tag there. But I didn't find that. This is example link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868013/editing-jpeg-exif-data-with-java     But it is for editing tag. I want to add new custom tags.